# Setting ACL recursive execute permission on a folder makes files executable

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, nginx, acl, access-control

Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running Nginx 1.18.0 and PHP-FPM to serve a website.

I create a new folder as document root in `/var/www`, owned by the the FPM user `foo`, that will host a site:

```
$ sudo mkdir foo
$ sudo chown -R foo:foo
$ sudo chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o= foo
$ sudo chmod -R g+s foo
$ ls -la

drwxr-s--- ... foo foo ... foo
```

I add Nginx to the `foo` group, but since I don't want it to be able to write, I set the group permission to `rX` above.

**I set a default ACL.** I want all new files to have these same permissions by default:

```
$ sudo setfacl -Rm d:u::rwX foo
$ getfacl foo

user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other::---
```

I make extra sure to use `rwX`, since I want directories to be traversable, but not make files executable by default.

Now, Alice and Bob want to work on some stuff in there, so I add them both to the `foo` group:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG foo bob
$ sudo usermod -aG foo alice
```

**I give Bob access.** I want to add ACL overrides so Alice and Bob, as human users in the `foo` group, are able to write. Bob first:

```
$ sudo setfacl -Rm u:bob:rwX,d:u:bob:rwX foo
$ getfacl foo

user::rwx
user:bob:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:bob:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

Bob tests his newfound god powers:

```
$ touch foo/bobfile
$ ls -la foo

drwxrws---+ ... foo  foo  ... .
drwxr-xr-x  ... root root ... ..
-rw-rw----+ ... bob  foo  ... bobfile
```

I note dutifully that `ls` now shows `bobfile` as having group write permissions, but I know that's only because `ls` represents the *highest available permission that applies to at least one entity,* not what every user has.

**I give Alice access.** I want her to have the same permissions as Bob:

```
$ sudo setfacl -Rm u:alice:rwX,d:u:alice:rwX foo
$ getfacl foo

user::rwx
user:bob:rwx
user:alice:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:bob:rwx
default:user:alice:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

**Now Alice can execute Bob's *file.*** Huh?

```
$ ls -la foo

drwxrws---+ ... foo  foo  ... .
drwxr-xr-x  ... root root ... ..
-rw-rwx---+ ... bob  foo  ... bobfile*
```

Indeed, Alice can now execute `foo/bobfile`. Meanwhile, owner Bob cannot execute his own file (as it should be).

If Alice creates a new file now, she can't execute it either - only `bobfile`, which was already there when her ACL was added.

Interestingly, Bob can't execute Alice's file either. To me, that points to a difference between ACL default and non-default entries.

I seem to be misunderstanding two things:

1. The significance of `x` vs. `X`, at least when it comes to ACLs. Why is Alice getting execute permissions on the existing file here?
2. The significance of ACL default vs. non-default rules, since adding an ACL entry with `X` makes existing files executable, but not new files.

What would be the correct command to achieve the intended result?

---

**Update:** It gets even weirder.

After the above outcome, I removed execute permissions on any files:

```
$ sudo chmod -R ug-x+X foo
```

This worked as intended.

However, I then removed Alice's ACL entries:

```
$ sudo setfacl -Rx u:alice,d:u:alice foo
```

Guess what? That made ALL files by `bob` or `alice` executable:

```
$ ls -la foo

-rw-rwx---+ ... alice foo ... alicefile*
-rw-rwx---+ ... bob   foo ... bobfile*
-rw-rw----+ ... foo   foo ... foofile
```

Testing execution of these files shows:

- alice is now again able to execute files owned by `bob`
- bob is now newly able to execute files owned by `alice`
- foo can now execute both `alice`'s and `bob`'s files.
- neither alice nor bob can execute their own files
- neither can execute any files owned by `foo`

I'd appreciate any help and insight here since I'm completely stumped by this behavior. Thank you.

---

Note: I posted this before on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1113951/giving-execute-permission-on-folder-with-acl-makes-files-executable-too) before realizing this is probably the better place. If that's breaking any rules, please let me know and I'll remove the other question.